# Passing variable with intents in a tab/multiple activities android app

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, android-activity, tabs

Hi Im a beginner to android development and Im doing an school assigment where we are to make n app which has a textfield for searching which will use that string to query a open API of rotten tomatoes. This will be shown as a list and later manipulated.

I have now come til the end. Searching for, adding to and getting similar movies all work fine (and the gui too) but im not able to delete from the db/list (which i save the movies to, if wanted) and I dont know why. I think I use the intents the right way but apparently not.

FULLCODE:

// MainActivity.java

```
     package geemoney.movieeservice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** TabHost (main container of tab view, the top rectangle) will have Tabs */
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        /** TabSpec used to create a new tab.
        * By using TabSpec only we can able to setContent to the tab.
        * By using TabSpec setIndicator() we can set name to tab. */

        /** tid1 is firstTabSpec Id. Its used to access outside. */
        TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid2");

        /** TabSpec setIndicator() is used to set name for the tab. */
        /** TabSpec setContent() is used to set content for a particular tab. */
        firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Search").setContent(new Intent(this,SearchTab.class));
        secondTabSpec.setIndicator("My List").setContent(new Intent(this,MylistTab.class));

        /** Add tabSpec to the TabHost to display. Adding the newly created tabs to its container */
        tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

// One of the two new classes/tabs, this one callse SearchTab

```
package geemoney.movieeservice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import database.DBAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SearchTab extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Map<String, String>> data;
    SimpleAdapter aa;
    Map<String, String> item;
    String apiKey = "chhgsd429xb9fs6wq3kqzhmk";
    String current = "";
    MylistTab mt = new MylistTab();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        /* First Tab Content */
        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        Button similarButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.similar);
        Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (current != ""){
                    add();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to select a list item",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        similarButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (current != ""){
                    similar();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to select a list item",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchstring);
                if ((!(userInput.getText().toString().isEmpty()))) {
                    search();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need insert a search string",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void add() {
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        String id = current.substring(current.indexOf("id=") + 3, current.indexOf(" ", current.indexOf("id=") + 3) - 1);
        String title = current.substring(current.indexOf("title=") + 6, current.indexOf("}", current.indexOf("title=")));
        String year = current.substring(current.indexOf("year=") + 5, current.indexOf(" ", current.indexOf("year=") + 5) - 1);
        db.open();
        db.insertTitle(id, title, year);
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added to DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    protected void search() {
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        EditText searchstring = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchstring);
        String query = searchstring.getText().toString().replace(' ', '+');
        String text = searchquery(query);

        try {
            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(text);

            JSONArray jsonArray = res.getJSONArray("movies");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
                item.put("id",jsonObject.getString("id"));
                item.put("title",jsonObject.getString("title"));
                item.put("year", jsonObject.getString("year"));
                data.add(item);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                   

        aa = new SimpleAdapter(SearchTab.this, data,
                R.layout.mylistview,
                new String[] {"title", "year"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,
                R.id.text2});
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
        lv.setDividerHeight(5); 

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                Map<String, String> s = data.get((int) id);
                current = s.toString();
                // HERE INTENT
                Intent i = new Intent(SearchTab.this, MylistTab.class);

            }});
    }

    private String searchquery(String searchString) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey="+apiKey + "&q="+searchString + "&page_limit=10");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("QueryDB", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    protected void similar() {
        data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        //id=12897, year=1999, title=The Matrix
        String id = current.substring(current.indexOf("id=") + 3, current.indexOf(" ", current.indexOf("id=") + 3) - 1);
        String text;

        text = similarquery(id);
        try {
            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(text);

            JSONArray jsonArray = res.getJSONArray("movies");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
                item.put("id",jsonObject.getString("id"));
                item.put("title",jsonObject.getString("title"));
                item.put("year", jsonObject.getString("year"));
                data.add(item);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                   

        aa = new SimpleAdapter(SearchTab.this, data,
                R.layout.mylistview,
                new String[] {"title", "year"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,
                R.id.text2});
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
        lv.setDividerHeight(5); 

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

                Map<String, String> s = data.get((int) id);
                current = s.toString();
                // HERE INTENT
            }});
    }

    private String similarquery(String id) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies/"+id+"/similar.json?apikey="+apiKey +"&limit=5");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("QueryDB", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

// mylisttab.java

```
        package geemoney.movieeservice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import database.DBAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MylistTab extends Activity {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Map<String, String>> data;
    SimpleAdapter aa;
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    String current = "";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylist);

        /* First Tab Content */
        Button deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (current != "") {
                    delete();   
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You need to select a list item",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        populate();
    }

    public void delete() {
        if (current != null) 
        {
            db.open();
            db.deleteTitle(current);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CURRENT IS:" +current, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.close(); 
        }
    }

    private void populate() {
        db.open();
        Cursor fetchInfo = db.fetchAllRecords();
        startManagingCursor(fetchInfo);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (TITLE,YEAR)
        String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE, DBAdapter.KEY_YEAR};

        // an array of the views that we want to bind those fields to (in this case text1,text2,text3)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        SimpleCursorAdapter aa = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MylistTab.this, R.layout.mylistview, fetchInfo, from, to);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
        lv.setDividerHeight(5);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

// activity.main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<TabWidget 
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</TabWidget>

<FrameLayout 
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

// mylist.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/remove" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/remove" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

// mylistview.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</LinearLayout>
```

// search.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchstring"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchstring"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/search" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/addTitle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/similar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search"
        android:text="@string/similar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, why cant I place an intent at searchtab in the method similar() (or earlier) where I get the ID and positive of it since im using it to populate mylist like:
There I get the ID by this code:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)      
{
Map<String, String> s = data.get((int) id);
current = s.toString();
```

And then just beneath it do like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MylistTab.this, SearchTab.class);
i.putExtra("var1", current);
startActivity(i);
```

And in the next acitvity:

```
current = getIntent().getExtras().getString("var1");
```

Why is this not possible? When i do like this and run the app delete wont work saying there is a nullpointexception somewhere in mylisttab and i will get transferred around the layouts(which i dont want).
Has it to do with intent-filters? Im not sure I have to use them in this scenario.

Comment: Why do you have problems? Do you have some code that you can show me?

Comment: Well I was able to make a similar version of an online solution i found. Now I have 2 tabs which takes the user to different classes and the content is changing sp everything is working but, since its not longer the mainclasses they do not have an xml connected to them as the main does - so how do I add widgets like buttons and such in these new classes? Do I have to use full java-code in the .javafiles?

Comment: Anyone? Still have sme problems. Today im gonna try use global variables instead, but i would like to use intetns if its possible (i wanna learn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad to hear you are embarking the Android world. Let me start by saying it is fascinating.

Answering your question, may I ask if you have any constraints for your homework? I see you have hard coded your inputs in the java files. You can (and i recommend) defining all of your screen widgets (buttons, inputs, images, etc) in a xml layout and inflate them on activity's onCreate method.

Example taken from Ioshed (Google IO app)

XML (my_activity.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/choose_account_intro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java (MyActivity.java)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
}
```

Also, you could use the Fragments API which, to my understanding, is the correct way to make apps nowadays. Fragments help you modularize parts of your app's ui and behavior by creating small compoments that can be link via an activity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, im on my way on solving and understanding this. Its fascinating =)

Comment: No problem. I would recommend and encourage you to understand and use the Fragments API in your work. If any doubts arrise, don't hesitate on asking again here at SO. Cheers.

Also, don't forget to mark as solved your question if all your doubts are resolved.

Comment: Andres now I have made many changes and this is how it looks now. It works GUI-wise and the query is also ok without errors, only I cant make the fetched data to go into the listview of mine - Do you have any input how I do this?

Comment: Actully now I found out whats wrong, my JSONarray "results" is not working as it should and dont get values. Why?

Comment: @Emanuel, could you please post the server json response? This could help debug the issue. Also, consider creating a new question thread here in StackOverflow if your the current issue on this question has been solved. Thanks. EDIT: I used jsonlint.com to verify the server JSON. It seems ok. Please attach the response you are receiving in the device.

Comment: Thanks Andres but as it happened I figured it out myself after some struggle :)

Comment: Andres, do you have any input on this last question? As you can see I have updated the orginal post just now.